# Why is __proto__ empty for this module?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to understand JS objects better, and am experimenting with the [pg module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pg) for node.js.  My question is, why does the created object have no `__proto__` property?

```
var pg = require('pg');

console.log('proto: %j', pg.__proto__);

if ('connect' in pg) {
    console.log("connect exists");
}
```

The output, when I run `nodejs test.js` is:

```
proto: {}
connect exists
```

And in the pg module itself, I can see that the `connect` method is attached to the constructor's prototype:

```
PG.prototype.connect = function(config, callback) {
```

What magic is going on that my `pg` object has this `connect` method, but has an empty `__proto__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` replaces `%j` with result of `JSON.stringify`. JSON doesn't support functions, so they are omitted. Just check `typeof pg.__proto__.connect === 'function'`

Comment: So it does.  `console.log(pg.__proto__)` (without the %j conversion) outputs what I would expect. Thanks.